# Postfix not receiving external mail and local mail stuck in queue

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

I have an issue that I can't find solution for. My Postfix server crashed, I re-installed it, but now, and no matter what I do, I can't get it to forward incoming emails to its designated domain. I can send among local users. This is from main.cf:

When I try inet_interfaces = all, it stops receiving all together, and when put back to Localhost, they come back in but get stuck in queue with connection refused.

```
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
inet_interfaces = localhost

myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

Here's the postconf -n

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

```
Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance
```

---

```
Jun 24 18:45:02 ns10 dovecot: master: Dovecot v2.2.36 (1f10bfa63) starting up for imap, pop3 (core dumps disabled)
Jun 24 18:45:04 ns10 spamd[1374]: spamd: server started on IO::Socket::IP [127.0.0.1]:783, IO::Socket::IP [::1]:783 (running version 3.4.0)
Jun 24 18:45:04 ns10 spamd[1374]: spamd: server pid: 1374
Jun 24 18:45:04 ns10 spamd[1374]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 1869
Jun 24 18:45:04 ns10 spamd[1374]: spamd: server successfully spawned child process, pid 1870
Jun 24 18:45:04 ns10 spamd[1374]: prefork: child states: IS
Jun 24 18:45:04 ns10 spamd[1374]: prefork: child states: II
Jun 24 18:49:58 ns10 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=98.249.241.145, lip=167.172.230.150, session=<GW5hfYfFP8di+fGR>
Jun 24 18:49:58 ns10 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=98.249.241.145, lip=167.172.230.150, session=<JLxnfYfFQMdi+fGR>
Jun 24 18:49:58 ns10 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=98.249.241.145, lip=167.172.230.150, session=<cslnfYfFQcdi+fGR>
Jun 24 18:49:59 ns10 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=98.249.241.145, lip=167.172.230.150, session=<xQR6fYfFQsdi+fGR>
Jun 24 18:50:02 ns10 dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=98.249.241.145, lip=167.172.230.150, session=<4B6gfYfFQ8di+fGR>
Jun 24 18:50:04 ns10 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=98.249.241.145, lip=167.172.230.150, session=<+OC6fYfFRMdi+fGR>
Jun 24 18:50:04 ns10 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=98.249.241.145, lip=167.172.230.150, session=<P2rAfYfFRcdi+fGR>
Jun 24 18:50:04 ns10 dovecot: imap-login: Aborted login (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=98.249.241.145, lip=167.172.230.150, session=<s6DAfYfFRsdi+fGR>
Jun 24 18:50:29 ns10 postfix/postqueue[3955]: warning: Mail system is down -- accessing queue directly
Jun 24 18:50:32 ns10 postfix/postfix-script[4067]: starting the Postfix mail system
Jun 24 18:50:32 ns10 postfix/master[4069]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Jun 24 18:50:33 ns10 postfix/qmgr[4071]: C9D697CA466B: from=<info@dolorendyacon.com>, size=1470, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 24 18:50:33 ns10 postfix/smtp[4073]: connect to mail.dolorendyacon.com[167.172.230.150]:25: Connection refused
Jun 24 18:50:33 ns10 postfix/smtp[4073]: C9D697CA466B: to=<info@dolorendyacon.com>, relay=none, delay=12202, delays=12202/0.02/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.dolorendyacon.com[167.172.230.150]:25: Connection refused)
Jun 24 18:50:37 ns10 postfix/smtpd[4184]: connect from ns10.intrelligentsystems.com[::1]
Jun 24 18:50:37 ns10 postfix/smtpd[4184]: 756339804222: client=ns10.intrelligentsystems.com[::1]
Jun 24 18:50:37 ns10 postfix/cleanup[4190]: 756339804222: message-id=<83344af7190efe61e6e8ffb891c66e6c@login.intrelligent.com>
Jun 24 18:50:37 ns10 postfix/qmgr[4071]: 756339804222: from=<lblanca@intrelligent.com>, size=1469, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 24 18:50:37 ns10 postfix/smtpd[4184]: disconnect from ns10.intrelligentsystems.com[::1]
Jun 24 18:50:37 ns10 postfix/smtp[4073]: connect to mail.intrelligent.com[2604:a880:800:c1::463:f001]:25: Connection refused
Jun 24 18:50:37 ns10 postfix/smtp[4073]: connect to mail.intrelligent.com[167.172.230.150]:25: Connection refused
Jun 24 18:50:37 ns10 postfix/smtp[4073]: 756339804222: to=<lblanca@intrelligent.com>, relay=none, delay=0.05, delays=0.05/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mail.intrelligent.com[167.172.230.150]:25: Connection refused)
```

---

```
     netstat -tuplen | grep 25
tcp        0      0 10.108.0.2:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25         18467      1165/named
tcp        0      0 10.17.0.5:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25         18465      1165/named
tcp        0      0 167.172.230.150:53      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25         18463      1165/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25         18461      1165/named
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          156921     23047/master
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      25         18563      1165/named
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      25         18457      1165/named
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          156922     23047/master
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      25         18564      1165/named
udp        0      0 10.108.0.2:53           0.0.0.0:*                           25         18466      1165/named
udp        0      0 10.17.0.5:53            0.0.0.0:*                           25         18464      1165/named
udp        0      0 167.172.230.150:53      0.0.0.0:*                           25         18462      1165/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           25         18460      1165/named
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                25         18455      1165/named
```

Comment: What does the log files show?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see where to place it. Sorry

Comment: include excercepts in your post, or add to a pastebin, for instance www.pastebin.com

Comment: I think I placed it correctly

Comment: Does your provider block port 25 incoming and/or outgoing?

Comment: I've never had any issues. I tried sending a large mailing list and it crashed. I use Vtiger as the mail client. I can send but, it won't receive unless it's local. Port 25 is open and listening.

Comment: What does the logs show when you comment out the `inet_interfaces`-line?

Comment: Hi, still connection refused

Comment: I've just contacted DO and they said that there are no p25 issues on their end.